# Why is SUM() and COUNT() returning different values?

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I have two near identical queries and I'm trying to understand why they're returning different results. I would like to produce a table with a `user_id` and a `food_orders` column showing how many items each user has ordered. These queries produce this table but calculate different results in the food_orders column in some rows.

My questions are why is this and which should I use?

A simplified version of my queries are below.

Query 1 (using COUNT):

```
WITH order_made AS (
    SELECT restaurant_id,
           count(
                   CASE
                       WHEN item LIKE '%_angus' then 1
                       WHEN item LIKE '%_organic' then 1
                       WHEN item LIKE '%_lean' then 1
                       ELSE 0
                       END)
               AS burgers
    FROM mcdonalds.specialist_orders
    GROUP BY mcdonalds.specialist_orders.user_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT restaurant_id,
           COUNT(
                   CASE
                       WHEN item LIKE 'salad%' THEN 1
                       WHEN item LIKE 'tomato%' THEN 1
                       WHEN item LIKE 'potatoes%' THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                       END)
               AS vegetables
    FROM public.bulk_orders
    GROUP BY public.bulk_orders.user_id),
```

Query 2 (using SUM):

```
WITH orders_made AS (
    SELECT user_id, SUM(food_orders) AS food_orders
    FROM (SELECT user_id,
                   CASE
                       WHEN item LIKE '%_angus' then 1
                       WHEN item LIKE '%_organic' then 1
                       WHEN item LIKE '%_lean' then 1
                       ELSE 0
                       END
               AS food_orders
    FROM mcdonalds.specialist_orders
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id,
                   CASE
                       WHEN item LIKE 'salad%' THEN 1
                       WHEN item LIKE 'tomato%' THEN 1
                       WHEN item LIKE 'potatoes%' THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                       END
               AS food_orders
    FROM public.bulk_orders
    GROUP BY user_id)
```

Comment: I suspect the `COUNT` version is just returning all rows as it will count all the 0s, while `SUM` is actually what you want. If you remove the `ELSE 0` from the `CASE WHEN` then I think they should agree (because then the `COUNT` won't pick up null values).

Comment: How many numbers are there in the list `1,0,0,0,1`? What is the total when you add up each of `1,0,0,0,1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `COUNT` function count when the value isn't NULL (include 0) if you don't want to count, need to let `CASE WHEN` return `NULL`

so if you remove `ELSE 0` from your `CASE WHEN` or use `ELSE NULL` to instead, that result would be as same as `SUM`

```
WITH order_made AS (
    SELECT restaurant_id,
           count(
                   CASE
                       WHEN item LIKE '%_angus' then 1
                       WHEN item LIKE '%_organic' then 1
                       WHEN item LIKE '%_lean' then 1
                       END)
               AS burgers
    FROM mcdonalds.specialist_orders
    GROUP BY mcdonalds.specialist_orders.user_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT restaurant_id,
           COUNT(
                   CASE
                       WHEN item LIKE 'salad%' THEN 1
                       WHEN item LIKE 'tomato%' THEN 1
                       WHEN item LIKE 'potatoes%' THEN 1
                       END)
               AS vegetables
    FROM public.bulk_orders
    GROUP BY public.bulk_orders.user_id),
```